# C++ memory leaks with unordered_map

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl

I've discovered that I have a memory leak somewhere in my application but I've been having trouble narrowing it down.  I've tried using the function `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` as instructed in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x98tx3cf.aspx) but it doesn't show file names.  So, I've been trying to find the first point of memory leaks (as there seem to be quite a few according to the output) by placing calls to this dump function at various points.  It seems that I am getting a lot of them straight away very early in my constructors for objects.

Upon further investigation, I seem to be getting them with definitions for `std::unordered_map` even to the point where having a simple main function that just declares a local variable has a memory leak.

For example the following code produces a memory leaks:

```
void main()
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // executing this line, no memeory leaks found

    std::unordered_map<int, int> intMap;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // executing this line, memeory leaks found
}
```

I'm completely confused at this point and get the feeling that chasing this is not going to help me find the memory leak that I am originally noticed.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The declaration `void main()` is non-portable: the only portable declarations of `main()` return `int` (and, yes, I realize that the code isn't portable as it uses compiler specific functions to check for apparently leaked memory).

Comment: parts of the STL use pooled memory optimizations, you can safely ignore any memory leaks from an STL container...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you expect that `std::unordered_map<T>` doesn't hold any memory while you are clinging to an object? That seems to be an unreasonable assumption! At the very least, you should destroy the object you created:

```
int main()
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // executing this line, no memeory leaks found

    {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> intMap;
    }

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // executing this line, memeory leaks found
}
```

I don't know whether this will release all memory but it has a better chance. The standard C++ library may still keep some memory pooled in its memory allocation mechanism.

Comment: Ok scoping the variable seems like such an obvious thing now you've mentioned it. My amateur thought processes are showing there. The only I can foresee there though is for member levels variables of this type when trying to find leaks in classes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

What's the definition of a memory leak except "memory that has been allocated and not yet freed"?

If the `unordered_map` constructor allocates any memory internally, then you have your "leak" right there. Try putting it in its own scope and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 3):

It only makes sense to call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` when you have freed everything you've allocated.

As the other answers have stated, you have a `unordered_map` in scope and this object has allocated memory. Once it's gone, the allocations will go with it. So wrap it in a scope!